# Internet Connection trouble with Xubunu

Tags: wireless, networking, internet

Recently just switched over to Xubuntu 14.04.1 and installed perfectly. However it says that I am connected to the Wireless network, but is not allowing me to connect to the internet (Or timing out). Is there any way to fix this using a flash drive to install the missing drivers (if there is any)? I do not have an Ethernet cord so connecting to the internet seems fairly impossible at the moment.

Also since I am fairly new at this, how do I go about seeing if I missing a drivers?

Comment: Can you identify the wireless card?

Comment: If you cannot identify the WiFi card, please provide: Brand and model of your PC/Laptop.  Then go to a terminal `[Ctrl][Alt][T]` and then type `lspci` and `lsusb` copy-paste the output *in your question*.  Press [edit] to modify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this from terminal to identify what you need:

## lspci -nn | grep 0280

Then find your driver from other pc (google for linux driver of your device) and move it to laptop with flash-drive.
Finaly from settings go to additional drivers and activate it.

You may want to search more info if you don't get it working.
http://docs.xubuntu.org/1304/internet-networks.html